# validate data from url without api

Tags: php, html, parsing

Hello StackOverlow fellows,

I am trying to build a PHP based forum for CAs. I want the forum to be exclusive for CAs only. Now, at the sign up page their membership number would be asked. This membership number needs to be validated from another URL. Now, the problem is that the other site doesn't provide any api for this and one has to manually put the membership number and submit to get the membership details.

The URL of site where one can check status is:
`http://220.225.242.179/locm.asp`

Sample membership number: 406691

The site uses post data so no argument can be passed via URL.

Is there anyway this can be automated? Or i need to manually approve all registrations?

Comment: can you create a table on the new site of membership info from the other site, and reference that when users sign up?

Comment: @rich701: No, don't have access to other site database.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script that scrapes the content of that link. The problem is that you have to maintain that script everytime that the website gets updated.

As the form doesn't have any captcha or a mechanism to prevent automated queries you can setup something easy.

You can make the post request using CURL:

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://220.225.242.179/locm.asp';
$fields = array(
    'mrn' => "406691",
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Take a look to the following links:

https://github.com/fabpot/goutte

http://www.jacobward.co.uk/web-scraping-with-php-curl-part-1/

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1593271204/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271204)